# UISwitch Not Responding To NSUserDefault Changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch in my app along with one in my settings bundle with the same functionality.  The UISwitch in my app however is not saving its settings properly.  Can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Set the application defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"No" forKey:@"isKgs"];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)switchChanged
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:unitSwitch.selected forKey:@"isKgs"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"SwitchGhanged:");
}

-(void)cellForRowAtIndexPath
{
    [unitSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];           
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isKgs"]) 
    {
       [unitSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
    }
}
```

And here is the settings bundle
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:unitSwitch.on forKey:@"isKgs"];
```

Use the `on` property for setting.

Comment: Don't I need to set default settings that register if the user has never opening the settings page?  If the app has never saved a value for a particular key, you get the value you specified in registerDefaults. Otherwise, the saved value overrides the starting value

Comment: Thanks, i think the "on" instead of "selected" fixed everything.

Comment: @Faisal You need to do it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `on` on the UISwitch:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:unitSwitch.on forKey:@"isKgs"];
```

EDIT: No need to test as unitSwitch.on is already BOOLEAN, you can assign it directly.

Comment: Add this to cellForRow or switchChanged method?

Comment: This code should replace the first line of your switchChanged method.